# Can I add a country to a release already rolled-out?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I am using Google Play. I have a release that is rolled out to two specific countries already. Can I add a third country to this release without building my app again with a new version and/or starting a roll-out again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, go to your track (Production, open testing , …etc),  select `countries / regions` then click on "add countries / regions"

[image: screen]

Comment: Just for clarification: Does doing this release the existing version to the selected country or do I have to roll-out a new release?

Comment: Your existing version will be come available in the new added countries. But it could take up to 48 hours to take effect